# custom table_name for table users with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

for my app, I have several tables for users (franceusers, belgiumusers, ...) and I would like to use one or another depending on domain
I tried with table_name_prefix and table_name but it seems to not work

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
rolify
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
# :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, #:confirmable,
:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

def self.table_name
debugger
'franceusers'
end

def self.table_name_prefix
debugger
'france'
end
end
```

thanks to debugger, I can see that is called but not self.table_name_prefix. And even if self.table_name if called, devise search users in tables users instead of franceusers

in console
User.table_name => "franceusers"

User.table_name_prefix => "france"

more weird, im also using activeadmin, and when I browse users list, I have an error :
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'franceusers.id' in 'order clause': SELECT users.* FROM users ORDER BY franceusers.id desc LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0

it seems it can find table_prefix for field but not for FROM.

do I do anything bad ? is there another way to change users table name ?
I cant join all users tables in one as it is a directive of my boss :-s

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have different types of users and you have a requirement from above that they must each be in different databases then I would probably just create a user class for each (assuming we're talking 5-10 and not 100s).

Have a FranceUser and a SpainUser etc. Then extract the common devise logic out into a module that you can include in each class. You will also need to override the login/register/etc controllers for it to be able to join the various tables together and search for the correct user. You will also need to implement things like email uniqueness constraints across multiple database tables. Basically its sounds like a really bad idea and you will have to do a lot of work that you otherwise get for free with devise.

It is doable but I would suggest you find out what use case your boss hass for splitting your data up into multiple tables and then finding a better way to solve his problem. It might just be something as simple as wanting easy reporting and there are much simpler and more elegant ways of solving those problems than using devise and then overriding half its functionality.

Good luck :)